# mktime() in PHP is giving me the wrong year when included in a date() function

Tags: php, date, mktime

This one is killing me.

I'm trying to write a tiny function that simple outputs the date two days from now. I'm using the following code (in PHP emulator) to try to get it working:

```
echo date('d/m/Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, date("d")+2, date("m"), date("Y")));
```

The output I get is `03/07/2014`, clearly the wrong date (I expect to get `03/17/2014`).

What's killing me is that when I try

```
echo date("Y");
```

I get the correct output, `2013`.

What is happening inside the date function that is ruining my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the `day` and `month` parameters to [`mktime()`](http://php.net/mktime) backwards:

> int mktime ([ int $hour = date("H") [, int $minute = date("i") [, int
>   $second = date("s") [, int **$month** = date("n") [, int **$day** =
>   date("j") [, int $year = date("Y") [, int $is_dst = -1 ]]]]]]] )

So, you are looking for:

```
echo date('d/m/Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d") + 2, date("Y")));
```

Answer (score 4):

There are easier ways to do this. [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) makes working with dates easier than `mktime()` and `date()`.

```
$now = new DateTime();
$now->modify('+2 days');
$two_days = $now->format('m/d/Y');
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/LOLnXh)

Comment: Can you briefly explain what the `->` means?

Comment: It's part of PHP's object syntax. See [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php) (scroll down to `classes and objects`)